# Does Web API support multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-web-api2

I would like to know that Web API support multithreading or not. How does web api handle multiple requests, sequentially or parallely?

Please advise.

~Rashi

Comment: would you consider answering this question with any knowledge you've gained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this

[Must I add explicit threading to my Web API REST methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230093/must-i-add-explicit-threading-to-my-web-api-rest-methods)

and

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38501/Multi-Threading-in-ASP-NET

Might be worthwhile to search before asking :)

Answer (score 3):

The Web API already has a pool of threads to use, so no need to worry about multithreading.

Comment: Why does a thread pool resolve in a programmer not having to worry about threading?